# How to create android project from weex

Tags: weex

I can't add platform from weex, only from weexpack

```
drew@drew-Aspire-E1-571G ~/Work/Weex/awesome-project $ weexpack  platform add android
Error: Current working directory is not a weexpack project
```

and I cannot compile weex to android project

.

Answer (score 2):

If you use weex-toolkit, you should create some files and dirs by yourself, including:

dirs:

- web
- platforms
- plugins

files:

- android.config.json
- ios.config.json
- config.xml

Edit `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.alibaba.weex" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp1</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

In the current version, you can also use `weex create` to create weexpack project.

And of course, a starter kit maybe also helpful for you: https://github.com/elemefe/weex-vue-starter-kit

Comment: Thanks for answer and thanks for starter-kit.
But now another question, about plugins: how I can run Natjs plugins.
In weex-pack project, these plugins run only in *.we files...
In your starter-kit I see only  *.vue  files and *.we not compiled.

Comment: @AndreyBosonchenko It seems that the plugins is too old. The current weex version have changed `.we` to `.vue` and no longer maintain `.we`. But fortunately, it is easy to migrate from `.we` files to `.vue` grammar